# Rancher Installation Questions

Tags: rancher

I am new in Kubernetes and associated components.

I am trying to install Rancher 2.6.2 on a docker and my question is;
Do I need to install Kubernetes prior to Rancher Installation?
Do I need to run `'sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16 --ignore-preflight-errors=all`' command prior to Rancher Installation?

Please assist.

Best Regards,

Sujan

Answer (score 0):

To get Rancher quickly started on a single node, you just need docker installed on that node. Rancher spins up K3S cluster within a docker container so you get Rancher UI. Using it you can spin up other RKE or cloud provider base K8S clusters. It is a KIND setup and is useful for Dev or POC only.

However, if you want to have a more robust infrastructure to run Rancher in production, you should have a K8S cluster first (using RKE or other means) and then install Rancher using helm on top of that cluster. Rancher has good documentation for all steps including SSL certificate management to deploy Rancher on a K8S cluster.

Answer (score -1):

Rancher is only a tool to manage Kubernetes clusters, it can create the cluster on the cloud or connect to an existing cluster.

so for your question, yes you need to create the cluster beside the Rancher installation, and then connect the cluster to Rancher

Comment: Thank you Mendi. But within Rancher, there is an option available to create cluster.  If this option is already available in Rancher then why we need to create Kebernetes cluster first. What are the pre-requisites for Rancher installation. I did these steps. Install docker, Install kubernetes (without cluster)and then install Rancher but installation showing lots of error.

Comment: Hi Sujan, as far as I know, Rancher can create only on Cloud (any cloud provider), and you want to create the cluster locally with kubeadm, so then you need to create the cluster separately, and then add it to rancher (with the import cluster and not create new).

Comment: why did you say that Rancher can't create cluster on prem (bare metal)? as far as I know you have Custom option in rancher gui where you can create your own cluster.. or is it just for vm?